# Analyze Salesforce Data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, r

I can see this question getting kicked out for being so stupid, but I'm going to ask it anyways.

I have always worked with data that is in a database.  A DBA sitting down the hall put data into a database for me and I carved it up with SQL or exported it and was beginning to learn how to use R.  Well, I'm at a new place now and it has Salesforce data available to me through API's.

How the heck do I get this data?  Can I get this data into a MySQL database?  I'm going to want to do analytics on it as well as link other data to it from say Zendesk, klipfolio, web data etc.  I'm going to be working with a lot of API's and this is all new to me.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000guZeAAI):

```
Administration Setup > Data Management > Data Export > select desired objects
```

Looks like this will export it as a zipped CSV. Unzip this and load it into R or mysql or whatever you wish. Hope that helps, if you've further issues, do leave a comment.

Comment: yeah, the Salesforce community sorta makes sense as a resource for this question.  Thanks very much